# Telnet to Gmail SMTP server timeout

Tags: email, gmail, smtp

I'm doing some testing of SMTP servers. I want to see the capabilities returned by the server in response to a `EHLO`. Gmail is timing out for SMTP:

```
$ dig gmail.com mx

; <<>> DiG 9.8.5-P1 <<>> gmail.com mx
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60432
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 5, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;gmail.com.         IN  MX

;; ANSWER SECTION:
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  20 alt2.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  5 gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  40 alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  10 alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
gmail.com.      3599    IN  MX  30 alt3.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
```

And:

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com smtp
Trying 74.125.29.26...
telnet: connect to address 74.125.29.26: Operation timed out
Trying 2607:f8b0:400d:c04::1a...
telnet: connect to address 2607:f8b0:400d:c04::1a: No route to host
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I'm not sure if this is Verizon blocking the connection from a DHCP block, if the problem lies elsewhere, or if Google just does not offer SMTP any longer (perhaps due to all the privacy violations of the US and other governments).

Does Google/Gmail still offer SMTP at port 25?

Comment: _Does Google/Gmail still offer SMTP at port 25?_ Nope, it's at port 465/587

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are gmail's MX servers, used to **receive** mail, and they accept connections to port `25` from here:

```
# telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com smtp
Trying 173.194.65.27...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP b6si7271885eem.150 - gsmtp
```

While they technically **are** SMTP servers, they're not used to forward clients email, but only to
*accept* mail **from** other server to `@gmail.com` accounts.

To send mail with gmail use `smtp.gmail.com`, and yes, it responds on port `25` too:

```
# telnet smtp.gmail.com 25
Trying 173.194.65.108...
Connected to gmail-smtp-msa.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP n1sm10228410eey.12 - gsmtp
```

Answer (score 1):

No it doesn't offer cleartext SMTP on 25 anymore, goes on SSMTP on 465.